# Evaluating $\sum_{n∈N}1/n^2$with the Poisson summation formula on Fejér kernel

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm asked to apply the Poisson summation formula to the Fejér kernel to obtain
an expression for
$$\sum_0^{\infty}1/(2k+1)^2$$.
Hence show 
$$\sum_1^{\infty}1/n^2=\pi^2/6$$
Here Fejér kernel is given by 
$$F_n=\frac{1}{n}(\frac{\sin(\pi n x)}{\sin(\pi x)})^2$$
with period of 1.

I can only show that $$\hat{F_n}(\xi)=(1-\frac{|\xi|}{n})\chi_{[-n,n]}$$

Any hints would be appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula for Fejer kernel in terms of Dirichlet kernel $D_n$. It is easy to write down $\hat {D_n}$ so you can compute  $\hat {F_n}$ easily from this. I will leave the starightforward calculations to you. I hope this hint helps.

Comment: Sorry I still can't figure out how to compute $\hat{D}_n$. It looks not that  starightforward to me.

Comment: $\hat {D_n} (k)=1$ if $|k| \leq n$ and $0$ otherwise.